# Can I get Apache 2.2 to set a particular response header if some other response header is missing

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, http-headers

I have an Apache 2.2 server running mod_proxy.  We had a scenario where a response came through from the origin corrupted, it didn't have any content-type or cache-control headers.  This meant that downstream proxies and clients cached the dodgy response.

What I would like to do is if the response doesn't have a content-type and cache-control header to insert a `Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache` header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to do this in Apache, you'd need to be running 2.4.  `mod_headers` is the normal means of manipulating response headers, and it's not flexible enough to do what you want.

In 2.4, something like this should work:

```
<If "-z resp('Cache-Control') && -z resp('Content-Type')">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache"
</If>
```

Answer (score 2):

from the [rewritecond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) manual, I haven't tested but it seems that you could do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cache-Control} ^$ [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} ^$
Header add Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that'll work only against request headers, not response headers.

Comment: So with mod_header you'll be able to use just `Header add`